# How to get customer billing and shipping information in magento2 .phtml files?

Tags: magento2, customer, shipping-address, billing-address

How to get checkout page information (firstname, lastname, address etc of customer)  ,
I have created one phtml file and the code is below

$address = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order');

```
        echo   $address->getBillingAddress()."<br/>";  
        echo   $address->getShippingAddress()."<br/>";
```

I need to get customer information irrespective of his/her login. 
how can I achieve it, thanks.

Comment: do you need logged in user data ?

Comment: No , what i exactly need is customer who has ordering his product he ll fill shipping details, i need those details like firstname, lastname, address, zipcode etc. "Irrespective of their login "

Comment: Okay, on checkout page while filling billing and shipping details, right ?

Comment: yeah i need those information in my .phtml file. How can i do this?

Comment: on order success page ?

Comment: its custom module .phtml file. I want to calculate my own tax for that i need to make a API call and i need to pass customer information also . i am not showing it in order success page it should be before making payment.

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if not solve.

Comment: Please accept and upvote answer if it's useful for you. So, this answer will helpful for other developer also. @ASHWINIMURTHY

Answer (score 2):

**Factory Method :**

You need to inject `\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory` and `\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory` in your construct

```
protected $_customerFactory;
protected $_addressFactory;

public function __construct(
    .............
    \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory
    .............
)
{
    .............
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->_addressFactory = $addressFactory;
    .............
}
```

then add this below code in your function

```
//get customer model before you can get its address data
$customer = $customerFactory->create()->load(1);    //insert customer id

//billing
$billingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
$billingAddress = $this->_addressFactory->create()->load($billingAddressId);


//shipping
$shippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();
$shippingAddress = $this->_addressFactory->create()->load($shippingAddressId);
```

**Object Manager Method :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerID = 1;
$customer = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory')->load($customerID);
$addressFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');

$billingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBilling();
$billingAddress = $addressFactory->load($billingAddressId);

$shippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShipping();
$shippingAddress = $addressFactory->load($shippingAddressId);
```

**Using Order ID :**

```
$orderID = 100;

$orderObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderID);

$shippingAddressObj = $orderObj->getShippingAddress();

$shippingAddressArray = $shippingAddressObj->getData();

$BillingAddressObj = $orderObj->getBillingAddress();

$BillingAddressArray = $BillingAddressObj->getData();
```

**Get order ID :**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$checkout_session = $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
$order = $checkout_session->getLastRealOrder();
$orderID = $order->getIncrementId();
```

**For better coding standard, Don't use Object Manager Directly.**

Comment: Yes :) One should never use \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance().
It defeats the purpose of dependency injection. +1 for explanation !

Comment: here $orderId is hard-coded, can please help me to get the orderId dynamically?

Comment: Want to get by customer ?

Comment: customer will be the guest user.  so !!!

Comment: Is it useful for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this all by `order id :`

Try below code :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($block->getOrderId()); // pass orderId
if($order->getCustomerId() === NULL){
    $firstname      = $order->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
    $lastname       = $order->getBillingAddress()->getLastname();
    $customer_name  = $firstname.' '.$lastname;
    $telephone_tmp  = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
    $customer_email = $order->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
    $postal         = $order->getBillingAddress()->getPostcode();
    $city           = $order->getBillingAddress()->getCity();
    $address_tmp    = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData('street');
    echo $customer_name."<-------- new customer";
}
/* getting Register Account Details */
else {
    $customer  = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($order->getCustomerId());
    //else, they're a normal registered user.
    $firstname = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
    $lastname  = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getLastname();
    echo $customer_name = $firstname.' '.$lastname ."<--------   exist customer";
}
```